# unable to send hindi character using sendkeys

Tags: python

am trying to send Hindi characters using sendkeys in python and gives bellow error.

code i used is: client.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='noteId']").send_keys("This is a Te$t m3ssag3: 123 'हिन्दी चार्ट'")

```
Trackback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\LearnPython\uninstall.py", line 23, in <module>
    client.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='noteId']").send_keys("This is a Te$t m3ssag3: 123 'हिन्दी चार्ट'")
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\marionette_driver\marionette.py", line 99, in send_keys
    self.marionette._send_message("sendKeysToElement", body)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\marionette_driver\decorators.py", line 23, in _
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\marionette_driver\marionette.py", line 710, in _send_message
    msg = self.client.request(name, params)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\marionette_driver\transport.py", line 283, in request
    self.send(cmd)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\marionette_driver\transport.py", line 248, in send
    data = obj.to_msg()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\marionette_driver\transport.py", line 48, in to_msg
    return json.dumps(msg)
  File "D:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "D:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "D:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable for That hindi Word, like

```
text='हिन्दी चार्ट'
param=text.encode('utf-8')
```

Than pass this variable `param` as per your requirement.